# Understanding bc in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I [came across](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bc-command-linux-examples/) following examples:

**Example 1**

```
$ x=`echo "var=500;var%=7;var" | bc`
$ echo $x
3
```

Here I dont get how `echo "var=500;var%=7;var" | bc` is evaluated. I have several doubts here:

**Q1.** What is exactly input to `bc`? Is it all of these commands: `var=500;var%=7;var`? Will love if someone explains how the exact execution happens here? I am guessing answers like below. Please tell me if I am correct:

> `echo "var=500;var%=7;var" | bc` is immediately executed. `echo` inputs sequence of three commands `var=500`m `var%=7` and `var` to `bc`. `bc` executes them in that exact sequence.

**Q2.** If answer to above question yes, I did not get what the last `var` does and why is it required? Or in other words, why `echo "var=500;var%=7" | bc` (without end `var`) does not work?

**Example 2**

```
$ echo 'n=8;m=10;if(n>m) print "n is greater" else print "m is greater" ' | bc -l
```

I have doubts similar to Q1 and Q2 here:

**Q3.** Does `bc` also evaluate `if-else` statements? If yes, why? I mean its "basic calculator". Is it really built to behave like language parser to understand different programming language control statements? (The same link above gives example which seem to input `for` and `while` loop to `bc`.)

Comment: Have you checked [`man bc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bc.1p.html)?

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html if you want to examine what's passing through the pipeline

Comment: The examples are unnecessary use of vars, `echo '500%7' | bc` does the same.

Comment: `%` and `%=` are modulus operators. The example code is so bloated because it uses variables, which upon assignment do not print their value. that's why `;var` needs to be explicitly printed.
> Explanation: Stores the result of 500 modulo 7 i.e. remainder of 500/7 in variable x and then display variable x as $x.